How can I make my deck finish last 10 years or more?
I'm in the Midwest and the paint on my deck starts cracking after a few years. I wonder if there are longer lasting finishes I can apply to my deck so that instead of sanding/painting it every few years, it can last for decades? I really hope there is a longer lasting solution. Even 10 years would be great.


The wood itself will barely last decades. This is why synthetics were invented. Also, while it's difficult to tell from this gritty image, your decking appears degraded already. If you were to investigate the hidden parts of the deck, such as the joist ends, you might find that it needs renovation anyway.

Short of getting rid of the paint, I don't think so.
In my experience, decks should generally not be painted; a penetrating stain is preferred. Or use a wood or composite that can be left bare. (Ipe is very expensive but hugely durable, for example -- though its rich color will fade under UV exposure.)

Wood expands, contracts, splits, twists and bows. When exposed to outside elements this happens with more frequency.  Trying to coat deck boards and not have to maintain and re coat for 10 years is a pipe dream.
If you truly want a deck that will need nothing but ordinary cleaning, replace the wood with composite boards.
Helped a friend do this in 2012 and the deck looks the same today as it did the day we were done.
